# Shiny Rookie Problems

Tags: r, shiny

I am brand new to Shiny and am watching Abhinav Agrawal's tutorials (currently on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwwQrEcXtfc)).

As far as I know, I have copied the code in the video exactly.  My code is as follows:

ui.R:

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel(title = "This is my first shiny app, hello shiny!"),
      sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("this is side bar panel"),
      mainPanel("this is the main panel text, output is displayed here")
      )
      )
    )
```

server.R:

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(
    function(input, output){

   }  

   )
```

However, while the code in the video produces a demonstration of the title, main panel, and sidebar panel, my code, when I run it by calling `runApp()` command in the console, produces the following warning:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3844
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

In addition, the shiny window that is produced, unlike the one in the video, is completely empty except for the word "shiny" appearing in all-lowercase letters in the top-left corner.

My `sessionInfo()` is as follows:

```
    R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

    Matrix products: default

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
    States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
    [4] LC_NUMERIC=C    LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] shiny_1.0.5

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.4.0  R6_2.2.2        htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.0     
    Rcpp_0.12.16    jsonlite_1.5    digest_0.6.15   xtable_1.8-2   
    [9] httpuv_1.3.6.2  mime_0.5
```

What is going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `sessionInfo()` as well as the code to invoke your shiny app, please? Your code does not throw any errors for me.

Comment: I added the info you requested.  Thanks!

Comment: Please check the encoding of your script files (`ui.R` and `server.R`) and make sure they are set to 'UTF-8'. See this article for a little more info: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html

Comment: Not related, but why not watch the [official tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) by RStudio?

Comment: Thanks!  I did fix the encoding (which wasn't UTF-8)... but the app still displays nothing but the word "shiny" in the top left corner.

Comment: I'm okay now.  The oficial tutorial has helped me.  Thanks!